# Is the meaning of this symbol "longevity"?

Tags: character-identification

I'm trying to determine the meaning of a particular character. Sparing the boring details, I'm trying to figure out what the meaning of this character is:

[image]

As near as i can tell it might be a symbol for "longevity" but, the symbol for that "shou" looks more like that below?

[image]

Is the meaning of the top character correct? Is there a difference between these two versions of the character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just [a variant of 壽](http://chardb.iis.sinica.edu.tw/meancompare/58FD/5900).

If you suspect a character is a variant you can always go to the [wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A3%BD) and refer to the Unihan data which will show common variants or use the service I linked above if it is something more obscure.

Comment: I can't open your link, so I give a new one here, http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/yitia/fra/fra00836.htm, Ministry of Education, Taiwan tells us that the second one 壽 is considered as orthographically correct in current Taiwan, though not every choice they made is orthographically, as put by a Peking University professor 李鐸 (http://dajia.qq.com/blog/305258009262110), the standard imposed by Republic of China government is not always rigid.