# What does this symbol mean on my ring?

Tags: character-identification

[image: Unknown symbol on my ring. Not sure if Chinese, but I've tried all written translations- and still no answer.]

Unknown symbol on my ring. Not sure if Chinese, but I've tried all written translations- and still no answer

Comment: 壽(寿), means longevity.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Is the meaning of this symbol "longevity"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/3568)

Answer (score 3):

壽 (shòu), longevity. Simplified: 寿

Common words: 长寿, long life; 寿司, sushi.

Comment: just writing it up now...beat me to it....