# What are the characters on this? (Character identified: 壽)

Tags: character-identification

What are the characters on this? One seems clearly to be 商, but I can't figure out the one that seems to be facing the other direction.

[image]

([larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF9vm.jpg))

Comment: Related: [What does this symbol mean on my ring?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/9507) [What do these two characters on cufflinks signify? (Characters identified: 福 and 壽/夀)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/28634) [Is the meaning of this symbol "longevity"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/3568)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the decorative variants of「壽」.

In isolation it's a bit hard to recognise, as usually it's accompanied by a multitude of other variations in a collective art piece category known as「百壽圖」.

[image]