# What do these two single-character calligraphic artworks mean? (Characters identified: 忍, 壽)

Tags: character-identification, calligraphy

My mother purchased calligraphy artwork with these two symbols many years ago and now I have them and do not know what they mean.  They are lovely, but I'd rather not hang them in my home without knowing what their meaning.

[image]

Comment: Related: [What does this symbol mean on my ring?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/9507) [What do these two characters on cufflinks signify? (Characters identified: 福 and 壽/夀)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/28634) [Is the meaning of this symbol "longevity"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/3568) [What are the characters on this? (Character identified: 壽)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/34418)

Answer (score 2):

忍 (traditional/simplified)：to resist or suffer; a more positive translation might be to endure or persist

壽 (traditional) / 寿 (simplified)：longevity; usually wishing an elder a long and happy life